# What is the word for a phrase which uses a homonym with two of its meanings?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, homonyms

For example, the phrase "I'm stuck on Band-Aid and Band-Aid's stuck on me" or "He books time to read books".

Comment: See [antanaclasis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antanaclasis)

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, the term [antanaclasis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antanaclasis) seems like the most appropriate word for the task.